# Character animations are not playing correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started creating my first very simple 2D platformer. Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR6TFcFuzI2bB7TMNIIBpKMQ&index=3) tutorial I am now adding move animations to my character (move, run, jump e.c.t.). Everything has worked perfectly until I made an edit to my player movement script (as instructed by the tutorial) which solves an animation issue of the player going back to the idle animation state from the crouch animation state when the crouch key was released but the player was still crouching (due to the player not being able to stand up because of an object over its head). When making the modifications to my code and running my game, the player now just constantly plays/unplays the crouch animation regardless of whether the player is actually in the crouch state.

The script used to control the character and its movements are shown below:

PlayerMovment.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    public float runSpeed = 100f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;
    


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Get user input
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;
        // Set animator paramaters
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
            animator.SetBool("isCrouching", true);
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
            animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false);
        }
    }

    // Update is called a fixed amount of times per second
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Move player
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
    
    // Function is called when player lands
    public void OnLanding()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }

    // Function is called whenever player crouches/uncrouches
    public void OnCrouching (bool isCrouching)
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouching", isCrouching); // this is the modification which was made to the code
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are following a tutorial, and have done so correctly you will have the same behavior they do, as a result, they will either fix it soon, or, your code is different to theirs..

Comment: Can you try to reproduce your bug with less code, so that it is easier to help you?

Comment: You posted too much code. Probably because you don't know where the problem is. Probably because you did no debugging. [You need to do that before posting](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: One thing I see is that when you call this line "if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))" in the PlayeMovement class you do not need this line "animator.SetBool("isCrouching", true);" Also on the same class after line "else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))" you do not need "animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false);"..... The reason is because you already are handling the IsCrouching parameter from the OnCrouchEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible causes for your problem.

So make the following changes:

1. In your PlayerMovement class change the Update method to this:

   ```
   void Update()
   {
       // Get user input
       horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;
       // Set animator paramaters
       animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

       if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
       {
           jump = true;
           animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
       }

       if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
       {
           crouch = true;
           //animator.SetBool("isCrouching", true); Remove this line of code
       }
       else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
       {
           crouch = false;
           //animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false); Remove this line of code
       }
   }
   ```

Those two lines of code are NOT needed because you handle the Crouching with the OnCrouch Event.

2. Make sure when you add the OnCrouching event handler method to the On Crouch Event in the Inspector window that you choose the TOP version of the OnCrouching method. 
   The one under Dynamic Bool and NOT the one under Static Parameters...
   [image]